# Freestyle without anti aliasing for pixel art (2.8)

Tags: freestyle, antialiasing, pixel-art

I've got a simple question that likely has a very complicated answer.

Simple enough, I need to know how to make these freestyle lines completely sharp. I'm trying to make pixel art. By default, freestyle has some hefty anti aliasing. I don't know which settings to change in order to make the lines totally solid, and I haven't been able to figure it out.

[image: anti-aliased freestyle lines]

Comment: I think AA is a property of the renderer rather than freestyle? Have you tried rendering with samples set to 1?

Comment: One option could be to pixellate a higher resolution render using the compositor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out!

Set the sampling to 1, and it will get the effect extremely close, I might have to touch these up a little bit in a 2D art tool, but the effort will be minimal.

[image]

Comment: This is a great way to make 2d pixel art.

Comment: Can you show your shader nodes for this flat shading?

Comment: Doesn't work when the freestyle line is thin and/or the output is small (32px). Well, it "works" but the black outline bleeds horribly in unexpected pixels everywhere and the result looks very bad.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can't switch off antialiasing for Freestyle, and you'd be better probably with separating the rendering twice - once with freestyle but with layer material override set to emission white.
Then you can use thresholds in the compositor to Make the freestyle pass completely black/ transparent (use math node - larger than). It seems the render itself is pixelated enough, so there won't be a problem.

Read more about View layers here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/layers.html#view-layers

And material override here:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/layers.html#override

[image: Find material override here:]

Comment: It looks like material override isn't available in the new blender 2.8, I did a lot of digging and just couldn't find it. I did manage to get the render layers separated though.

Comment: it's there, just tested and added a picture here too.

Comment: OH! Gotta be in cycles render. The option isn't available for eevee.
Oh no :c I'll have to remake all of my materials, wont I?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Constant in the ColorRamp.
In the render properties->Color Management->look->high contrast